# What is the origin of the prefix “be-”?

Tags: prefix

Let's take an example.

besuchen => to visit someone

suchen => search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't know it, but [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/be-) says it's an abbreviation of *bei* — which I find interesting, since there are other German prefixes that conserved the whole preposition (*an, auf,...,zurück*). Notice, that *bei* itself appears in that list (e.g. *beitragen*) but *bei-* is always a separable prefix. On the other hand *be-* is always an inseparable prefix. This is yields a mnemonic rule, which is always nice to have.

You might want to go directly to

> Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deuschen, dtv, 1997, ISBN 3-05-000626-9, Seite 501

or to [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=be-)'s entry.